# How to change laravel 5.4 permalink pattern?

Tags: laravel-5.4, permalinks

I was tasked to convert a website from an existing framework to Laravel. However, I meet with difficulty when dealing with permalink.

I want to keep the original pattern of the permalink from the old framework because the old permalink had been used a lot in Facebook posts. So if I change it, the old posts with the old links will not work anymore.

This is the old permalink pattern:

domain.com/article?id=123

However, the routing for laravel is like this:

domain.com/article/123

So, how do i change the route in laravel?

Example:

Route::get('/article/{post}', 'PostsController@show');

to

Route::get('/article?id={post}', 'PostsController@show');

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to develop the new app with Laravel and out-of-the-box links.  This would make ongoing maintenance and upgrades less likely to break things.

Then, set up a series of 301 redirects in your .htaccess file to manage the redirections from Facebook, etc.

Comment: I see, so we use 301 to redirect. thanks. By the way, i'm using nginx therefore I think I won't need .htaccess

Comment: No, it looks like you can add them direct in nginx config - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx

Comment: I have tested it, but it's not working. it returns 404 instead.  
  
# vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  
  
Within the server block:  
  
rewrite 301 ^/article?id=(.*)$ https://www.example.com/article/$1 permanent;  
  
Afterward, I restart the nginx:   
  
systemctl restart nginx

Comment: In the example, there wasn't '301' in it: 
rewrite ^/oldlocation$ http://www.newdomain.com/newlocation permanent;
Does that make any difference?

Comment: sorry, there is no 301 in the line #typo. I already done the correct way, but It does not help. I think the problem is that it only redirects based on directory: /dir1/(.*)$ but when I try something like path: /dir1?id=(.*)$ It does not work.